# If $\alpha$ separable over $F$ then $F(\alpha )/F$ is a separable extension.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

Let $K/F$ be a field extension and $\alpha \in K$ is algebraic over the field $F.$ Now suppose $\alpha$ is separable over $F.$ Then how can I show that $F(\alpha)/F$ is a separable extension, i.e., an arbitrary element of $F(\alpha)$ is a root of a separable polynomial over $F$ ?

I don't want to use embeddings and it is also clear when $F$ is a perfect field. I also know that if $\operatorname{char}(F)=p>0$ then $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha ^p).$ Using this only I want to get the result. Any help will be appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: I don’t know of any slick way of doing this without bringing embeddings in. Maybe somebody with a better viewpoint will do it for you, in which case I will slip away in embarrassment and delete this comment.

Comment: Sir is it not possible to prove for any $\beta \in F(\alpha) ,$ $F(\beta)=F(\beta ^p)$ ?

Comment: In characteristic $p$, that is surely true in a separable extension. In $F(\alpha)$, when $\alpha$ is a separable element, that will require a proof.  And of course, one will have to prove that your  criterion implies that the whole extension is separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three methods that do not directly refer to counting field embeddings are in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable2.pdf. The first two ways involve tensor products of fields and the third way uses derivations.

Comment: Personally, I think that those other methods are more elaborate and advanced than the method using embeddings.

Comment: @Lubin indeed, those other methods require more background, but for some generalizations of the meaning of "separable" they can be a more useful approach.  Personally I never liked arguments involving counting field embeddings over and over, and these other viewpoints have a certain elegance that I think the field embedding approach lacks, although I would not consider using these fancier methods in a first course on field theory.

Comment: I think I agree that the embeddings method is ugly, @KCd. And a pain in the neck to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the splitting field of  $f$ over $F$, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (and hence separable).